# Trying to query XML node by tag name in VBA, maybe namespace issue?

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xpath

I'm trying to get the `<content>` node from an XML document, using:

```
Private Sub test1()

Dim xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xmlNamespace As String
Dim nodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xml As String

Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xmlNamespace = "xmlns:d='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'"
xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNamespace
xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

xml = "<?xml version=""1.0""?>" & _
    "<entry xml:base=""https://example.com/Sites/xyz/_api/"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"" xmlns:d=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"" xmlns:m=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"" xmlns:georss=""http://www.georss.org/georss"" xmlns:gml=""http://www.opengis.net/gml"" m:etag=""&quot;39&quot;"">" & _
    "<id>Web/Lists(guid'abc')/Items(597)</id>" & _
    "<category term=""SP.Data.xListItem"" scheme=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme""/>" & _
    "<link rel=""edit"" href=""Web/Lists(guid'abc')/Items(597)""/>" & _
    "<title/>" & _
    "<updated>2018-07-28T02:06:34Z</updated>" & _
    "<author>" & _
    "<name/>" & _
    "</author>" & _
    "<content type=""application/xml"">" & _
    "<m:properties>" & _
    "<d:Id m:type=""Edm.Int32"">597</d:Id>" & _
    "<d:xId m:type=""Edm.Int32"">59</d:xId>" & _
    "<d:x2Id m:type=""Edm.Int32"">0</d:x2Id>" & _
    "<d:ID m:type=""Edm.Int32"">597</d:ID>" & _
    "</m:properties>" & _
    "</content>" & _
    "</entry>"


xmldoc.LoadXML xml
Set node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//content")

End Sub
```

The `node` value is always set to `nothing`, regardless of whether I use "content" or "//content".  I think there must be a namespace problem, because I'm able to successfully query `Id` with:

```
xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//d:Id")
```

So how do I query a node whose tag name is in the default namespace?

Update: QHarr's answer is correct, but if I want to query both the default namespace and another namespace, I need to set multiple namespaces as follows:

```
xmlNamespace = "xmlns:d='schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' xmlns:content='w3.org/2005/Atom'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the namespace at the top

```
xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:content=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"""
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub test1()

    Dim xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNamespace As String
    Dim nodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim xml As String

    Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlNamespace = "xmlns:d='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'"
    xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNamespace
    xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:content=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"""

    xml = "<?xml version=""1.0""?>" & _
          "<entry xml:base=""https://example.com/Sites/xyz/_api/"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"" xmlns:d=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"" xmlns:m=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"" xmlns:georss=""http://www.georss.org/georss"" xmlns:gml=""http://www.opengis.net/gml"" m:etag=""&quot;39&quot;"">" & _
          "<id>Web/Lists(guid'abc')/Items(597)</id>" & _
          "<category term=""SP.Data.xListItem"" scheme=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme""/>" & _
          "<link rel=""edit"" href=""Web/Lists(guid'abc')/Items(597)""/>" & _
          "<title/>" & _
          "<updated>2018-07-28T02:06:34Z</updated>" & _
          "<author>" & _
          "<name/>" & _
          "</author>" & _
          "<content type=""application/xml"">" & _
          "<m:properties>" & _
          "<d:Id m:type=""Edm.Int32"">597</d:Id>" & _
          "<d:xId m:type=""Edm.Int32"">59</d:xId>" & _
          "<d:x2Id m:type=""Edm.Int32"">0</d:x2Id>" & _
          "<d:ID m:type=""Edm.Int32"">597</d:ID>" & _
          "</m:properties>" & _
          "</content>" & _
          "</entry>"

      If Not xmldoc.LoadXML(xml) Then
        Err.Raise xmldoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xmldoc.parseError.reason
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//content:content")
    Debug.Print node.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: This works for selecting `content`, but when I try `Set node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//d:xId")` I get an error `Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'd'.`  Is there any way I can select from multiple namespaces?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out:
xmlNamespace = "xmlns:d='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' xmlns:content='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'"